# How to run sub Shell script in Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I want to execute a Shell command but I didn't know how to do a sub bash command correctly in my Makefile

```
import-bd:
    @while ! nc -z $(make ips | awk '/mysql/ { print $2 }') 3306; do \
        sleep 1 \
    done
    ...
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to quote the `$`s and add a `;`

```
import-bd:
    @while ! nc -z $$(make ips | awk '/mysql/ { print $$2 }') 3306; do \
        sleep 1; \
    done
```

When make sees a single `$`, it tries to do a variable expansion.  By writing `$$`, make passes a single `$` to awk (or, more precisely, it passes a single `$` to SHELL which invokes `awk`).  Also, the semi-colon after `sleep 1` is needed because make strips the newline.

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing semicolon after `sleep 1`.
Also make parses this line first then bash. You need to escape dollar with two dollars.

```
import-bd:
    @while ! nc -z $$(make ips | awk '/mysql/ { print $$2 }') 3306; do \
        sleep 1; \
    done
```